# Giving Access to IIS Application pool to read registry

Tags: windows, security, iis, registry

Although it seemed simple, I went to the registry folder I need and Right Clicked Permissions and gave accesss to IUS_IUSR, but still my web application could not access it.

At some point, i gave READ permission to Everyone and still access was denied.

It seems to me my IIS application pools are not being treated as normal users.

I've checked every possible solution and no result.

I even tried putting my data in different locations in the registry.

What can i do?

Answer (score 2):

FOUND ITTT!!!..

READ was not enough to access Registry from Web app. You need to give FULL CONTROL to the IIS User.